# Is this really an appropriate time to unit test?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm working my way through Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 and have just written this method:

```
public ViewResult Edit(int productId)
{
Product product = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductID == productId);
return View(product);
}
```

This seems pretty straightforward to me, but the author then writes a unit test for it. The test uses MOQ to create a mock repository object, so the only thing being tested is linq. Is the author writing the test as just another example of how to unit test, or is this normal practice? It seems to me that linq generally works and writing my own tests against it is redundant, but this is my first exposure to unit testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how the test has been written, but it likely does more than this.
For example, if the mock repository has been seeded with a Product with the specified productId, and the test also verifies that the related Product object that was seeded was returned from the query, then the test verifies that the function correctly matches the product with the specified id and returns an appropriate view.

With an additional test, which does not seed a Product into the repository, the test can verify that an incorrect product is not matched and that the correct behavior occurs when the product is not present.

Whilst the example seems trivial, the purpose of the unit test is not just to test the function now, it is to create a repeatable test that lives for the lifetime of the code, ensuring that during all future maintenance no subtle change is introduced which causes the behavior to change.

In isolation, many tests may seem trivial and even pointless. En masse, they provide a layer of protection against problems during the long term maintenance of the product.

Comment: I was thinking it may be something along those lines, and the two tests in the book do exactly as you say. Thanks for clearing that up. It helps me understand what I'm doing.